# How to find the source of a currently running kernel on my machine?

Tags: kernel, source

I have a `Linux 3.14.0 kernel(CentOS 6.2)` running on my machine, but the source isn't in `/usr/src/`.

Is there any way to find out the source from which it was compiled?

The source is most definitely somewhere on the machine, it was compiled by one of my colleagues. Also, these are lab machines not connected to the internet, hence the source code has to be manually copied and installed.

I just need to locate it based on the current kernel image.

Comment: How do you know the source is on your machine? What distro are you using? Did you compile the kernel yourself, or install it through your package manager? What kernel are you currently running?

Comment: added the info to the question.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvotes?

Comment: You provided *no useful* information in your question. Please see [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Ok. I have now added the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source` should be a symbolic link to the kernel source tree (if it was installed in a reasonable way).

Other than that

```
find / -type d -name "linux-3.14.0"
```

will look for the distribution directory of the 3.14.0 Linux kernel - that is the one you get when you unpack the tarball. If that fails,

```
find / -type d -name "linux-*"
find / -type f -name "Kbuild"
```

shouldn't give you too many false positives.

If you need to compile it then you can transfer the sources to the machine and do it from scratch, provided he compiled it with embedded `.config` (the `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` option). You can extract that either from `/proc/config.gz` (if supported by the kernel - see the `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` option), or with the `scripts/extract-ikconfig` script from the kernel source directory.

Apart from that, is asking your colleague entirely out of question?

Comment: Sadly he's out of reach right now. That's why I need to do it this way.

Comment: The `/lib/modules/` path worked. Thanks a ton!